# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Module using Guice

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection

I am trying to use the DI mechanism provided by [Google](https://github.com/google/guice), but when I run my application, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Module
at challenge.App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Module
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

The pom.xml file looks like:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
      <classifier>no_aop</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And the code where I am using it looks like:

```
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new DependenciesModule());
    IndexerController indexer = injector.getInstance(IndexerController.class);
```

And I have imported com.google.inject.Guice and com.google.inject.Injector

I have been checking for several places but I cannot see any relevant solution for this problems, I would appreciate a lot any glue.

Comment: I think you can remove <classifier>no_aop</classifier>. It is for version 3, not 4.

Comment: Hi @JunbangHuang thanks for answering, I have tried after your comments and still fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears like the usual issue with Maven in that *at runtime*, the dependency classes (e.g. the `Guice` classes) are not available to the JVM.

The easiest solution is to use explicit classpath specification *while running your app*:

```
java -cp 
/path/to/guice.jar:
/path/too/your-app.jar:
/path/to/other/classes/not/bundled/in/your-app.jar 
main.MyClass
```

(this is all on one line, split for better viewing).

The other solution is to use [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) which facilitates the creation of the *executable JAR* which you can simply run as `java -jar uber.jar`.

Comment: Thanks!, actually works after using maven creating the package and downloading the dependancies

Answer (score 5):

I was able to install the missing jar using:

```
sudo apt-get install libguice-java
```